# How can I convert woff to png?

Tags: png

I have an icomonn woff file, but now I need it as png, how?

Comment: what do you want to get out of it? A png of the whole alphabet? A specific text?

Answer (score 1):

Several options.
There are some woff converters to svg or even woff to png. I have not used them.

Another free option is creating a webpage using the font with the desired glyph and size and making a screen capture. I am not aware of many programs that use it, but web browsers do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the next services:

- https://convertio.co/woff-png/
- https://www.convertertools.net/woff-png
- https://www.onlineconvert.com/woff-file-to-png